# Error codes vs soap faults in soap based service

Tags: web-services, soap

I have developed a soap based web service. It returns java objects which contains data fields as well as error code and error message fields in case any error occurs or any exception is carched.

I have heard of soap fault messages that should be used for errors and exceptions.

My question is should i stick with current approach or should i use the soap fault messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SOAP Faults. That's why they were invented.

Using faults, your wsdl2java or equivalent tool will create a Java exception class for each fault type. When the fault occurs, the callers of the service can catch it using try/catch blocks. This makes it much easier to use the service, as it will not be necessary to check for error codes on every call.

It also means that code can't just forget to check for error codes.